# Flask не обновляет CSS

Tags: python, css, flask

**UPDATE**

Изучил проблему подробнее. CSS применяется при первом запуске, но далее не изменяется, даже если обновить и сохранить файл. Это, в принципе, логично звучит для папки `static`, но что-то мне подсказывает, что не так должно работать

**Проблема**

Суть проблемы в том, что `CSS` не обновляется на сервере `Flask`. `h1` все время красный, если подключать `CSS`, хотя в самом `CSS` файле указано, что он должен быть синим

При том запустив страницу через браузер все линкуется и работает хорошо

В принципе, всё видно на видео

Пробовал переустанавливать `Flask`, менять структуру проекта. В папке проекта больше нет других `.css` файлов, а в `.scss` стоит `h1 { color: green; }`, что, в принципе, тоже не красный

Исходный код

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css"> -->
    <title>Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    {%block body%}
    {%endblock%}
</body>

</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{%extends "layout.html"%}

{%block body%}
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

**style.css**

```
h1 {
  color: green;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Comment: в файле layout.html закомментированы строки подключения CSS, в реалии вы не забываете их расскоментировать?  Так же уточните, пожалуйста, как находится файл с style.css относительно файла layout.html

Comment: @virvaldium нет, конечно. Сейчас поправлю вопрос

Comment: так же попробуйте задать цвет через шетнадцатиричный формат: #00FF00;

Comment: @virvaldium пробовал, не помогло. Вообще при запущенном сервере через код страницы видно, какой файл в итоге линкуется. Когда я захожу на адрес localhost:5000/static/style.css я вижу старые, не обновленные данные. Проблема не в линке или синтаксисе, а в том, что не обновляется. Даже при перезапуске сервера полном

Comment: А как вы обновляете файлы?

Comment: @virvaldium просто пересохраняя. Сейчас нашел информацию, что проблема в кеше и, видимо, нужно как-то каждый раз новый файл идентифицировать. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714653/flask-css-not-updating

Comment: @virvaldium всё же непонятно как это использовать, пример кода есть, а куда и когда его впихнуть не ясно :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

Суть проблемы в кешировании браузером `CSS`. Из этого следует 3 возможных решения проблемы

1. Отключить кеширование для сайта (в продакшн так не пустишь, но должно сработать, сам не пробовал) ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066804/disabling-caching-in-flask))
2. Отдельно идентифицировать каждую версию стилей ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714653/flask-css-not-updating))
3. Делать "полное обновление" страницы через `Ctrl+Shift+R` или `Shift+F5` ([источник](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/7425/))

Мне больше по душе пришелся последний вариант, т.к. не придется менять код и в принципе меньше возни